# Postgres GENERATED AS IDENTITY column nullability

Tags: sql, postgresql-13

I want to create a table, which contains a nullable column having `GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY` option, therefore I run the following query:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  generated INTEGER NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
  data TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

But once I try to insert a row in the table, which `generated` field is `null` like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO my_table(generated, data) VALUES(NULL, "some data");
```

I get a null-constraint violation error.

However if I change the order of `my_table.generated` column properties:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  generated INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY NULL,
  data TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

It inserts rows, which generated field is `NULL`, without any issues.
Is this the expected behavior for the case?

Comment: Looks like a bug in the engine to me. Good catch! You should report it to the PostgreSQL team. I verified the bug affects PosgreSQL 10, 11, 12, and 13.

Comment: @TheImpaler, I appreciate your efforts, thanks!

Comment: You can report the bug in the mailing list: pgsql-bugs@lists.postgresql.org or at the end of the page https://www.postgresql.org/

Comment: @TheImpaler I wonder if this is intentional because the old `serial` "type" also included an implicit `not null` - but there is nothing in the manual that suggests that an identity column does this as well. So this might be "just" a documentation bug.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Could be. However, it's definitively a very odd behavior that the location of the `NULL` clause produces a different constraint in the database. Still looks like a bug to me.

Comment: @DeedeeMegadoodoo: why did you delete your answer? I think posting that the Postgres devs have accepted this [as a bug](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/7c02b352-a2e4-e71a-ae69-7e410daf5774%40postgresfriends.org) is a valid answer for this site.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I wasn't sure that my answer was related to both GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY and GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY expressions so I just deleted it, because they added tests for the latter case only. I read postgres sources a bit and it looks like these tests cover both of the expressions since they are both just variations of the same constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgres developers told me this is a bug since identity columns weren't supposed to be nullable (see the patch file under the [response](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/7c02b352-a2e4-e71a-ae69-7e410daf5774%40postgresfriends.org)).